# Is there a simple way in Java to get the difference between two collections using a custom equals function without overriding the equals?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm open to use a lib. I just want something simple to diff two collections on a different criteria than the normal equals function.

Right now I use something like :

```
collection1.stream()
           .filter(element -> !collection2.stream()
                                          .anyMatch(element2 -> element2.equalsWithoutSomeField(element)))
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and I would like something like :

```
Collections.diff(collection1, collection2, Foo::equalsWithoutSomeField);
```

(edit) More context:

Should of mentioned that I'm looking for something that exists already and not to code it myself. I might code a small utils from your ideas if nothing exists.

Also, Real duplicates aren't possible in my case: the collections are Sets. However, duplicates according to the custom equals are possible and should not be removed by this operation. It seems to be a limitation in a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: I think your approach is fine, and as efficient as it gets. You could just wrap it into a method (replacing the `equals...` call with the corresponding `BiPredicate`). For readability, I would replace the nested streaming in the filter criterion with a call to a method like `boolean contains(Collection<T>, T, BiPredicate<T, T>)`, but other than that, everything seems to be fine here.

Comment: I think that the key point here is the custom equals function without overriding the equals, not the difference itself.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva If this was the case, it should be made **much** clearer in the question. Although the answer would then be `BiPredicate<T, T> p = (t0,t1) -> t0.equalsWithoutSomeField(t1);`, which is a rather "trivial" syntactical detail...

Comment: There i agree, if he already has the `Foo::equalsWithoutSomeField` method, the correct answer would be a simple static function using that `BiPredicate`. The solution can use the same diff method that he already provide because it works fine. In the opposite case, and even to help people with a similar issue that do not have that `equalsWithoutSomeField`, the key would be here, in this method.

Comment: @Marco13 surely I can do that. I was looking for some hidden utils I'm unaware of that would do this OOTB by passing only the collections and the predicate. Just like I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/). `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` allows you to create a Set with a custom `HashingStrategy`. 
`HashingStrategy` allows the user to use a custom `hashCode()` and `equals()`. The Object's `hashCode()` and `equals()` is not used.

**Edit based on requirement from OP via comment**:

You can use `reject()` or `removeIf()` depending on your requirement.

**Code Example:**

```
// Common code
Person person1 = new Person("A", "A");
Person person2 = new Person("B", "B");
Person person3 = new Person("C", "A");
Person person4 = new Person("A", "D");
Person person5 = new Person("E", "E");

MutableSet<Person> personSet1 = Sets.mutable.with(person1, person2, person3);
MutableSet<Person> personSet2 = Sets.mutable.with(person2, person4, person5);

HashingStrategy<Person> hashingStrategy =
    HashingStrategies.fromFunction(Person::getLastName);
```

1) Using `reject()`:  Creates a new `Set` which contains all the elements which do *not* satisfy the `Predicate`.

```
@Test
public void reject()
{
    MutableSet<Person> personHashingStrategySet = HashingStrategySets.mutable.withAll(
        hashingStrategy, personSet2);

    // reject creates a new copy
    MutableSet<Person> rejectSet = personSet1.reject(personHashingStrategySet::contains);
    Assert.assertEquals(Sets.mutable.with(person1, person3), rejectSet);
}
```

2) Using `removeIf()`: Mutates the original `Set` by *removing* the elements which satisfy the `Predicate`.

```
@Test
public void removeIfTest()
{
    MutableSet<Person> personHashingStrategySet = HashingStrategySets.mutable.withAll(
        hashingStrategy, personSet2);

    // removeIf mutates the personSet1
    personSet1.removeIf(personHashingStrategySet::contains);
    Assert.assertEquals(Sets.mutable.with(person1, person3), personSet1);
}
```

**Answer before requirement from OP via comment:** Kept for reference if others might find it useful.

3) Using `Sets.differenceInto()` API available in Eclipse Collections:

In the code below, `set1` and `set2` are the two sets which use `Person`'s `equals()` and `hashCode()`. The `differenceSet` is a `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` so, it uses the `lastNameHashingStrategy` to define uniqueness. Hence, even though `set2` does not contain `person3` however it has the same lastName as `person1` the `differenceSet` contains only `person1`.

```
@Test
public void differenceTest()
{
    MutableSet<Person> differenceSet = Sets.differenceInto(
        HashingStrategySets.mutable.with(hashingStrategy), 
        set1, 
        set2);

    Assert.assertEquals(Sets.mutable.with(person1), differenceSet);
}
```

Person class common to both code blocks:

```
public class Person
{
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

**Javadocs:** [MutableSet](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/set/MutableSet.html), [UnifiedSet](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/set/mutable/UnifiedSet.html), [UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/set/strategy/mutable/UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy.html), [HashingStrategy](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/HashingStrategy.html), [Sets](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/factory/Sets.html), [reject](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/set/mutable/UnifiedSet.html#reject-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate-), [removeIf](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collection/mutable/AbstractMutableCollection.html#removeIf-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate-)

**Note:** I am a committer on Eclipse Collections

Comment: I thought this was it... but I don't want to remove the "duplicates" according to the custom hashing function. The Set should be built using to the real hashing function and then the diff function I need would use the custom one. So in your test case I would want person1 and person3 in the final Set. Close one though, might be useful for others.

Comment: I have updated the answer which satisfies your requirement. Please let me know if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Not as simple as what I was looking for, but really interesting!

Answer (score 4):

We use similar methods in our project to shorten repetitive collection filtering. We started with some basic building blocks:

```
static <T> boolean anyMatch(Collection<T> set, Predicate<T> match) {
    for (T object : set)
        if (match.test(object))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Based on this, we can easily implement methods like `noneMatch` and more complicated ones like `isSubset` or your `diff`:

```
static <E> Collection<E> disjunctiveUnion(Collection<E> c1, Collection<E> c2, BiPredicate<E, E> match)
{
    ArrayList<E> diff = new ArrayList<>();
    diff.addAll(c1);
    diff.addAll(c2);
    diff.removeIf(e -> anyMatch(c1, e1 -> match.test(e, e1)) 
                       && anyMatch(c2, e2 -> match.test(e, e2)));
    return diff;
}
```

*Note that there are for sure some possibilities for perfomance tuning. But keeping it separated into small methods help understanding and using them with ease. Used in code they read quite nice.*

You would then use it as you already said:

```
CollectionUtils.disjunctiveUnion(collection1, collection2, Foo::equalsWithoutSomeField);
```

Taking Jose Da Silva's suggestion into account, you could even use `Comparator` to build your criteria on the fly:

```
Comparator<E> special = Comparator.comparing(Foo::thisField)
                                  .thenComparing(Foo::thatField);
BiPredicate specialMatch = (e1, e2) -> special.compare(e1, e2) == 0;
```

Comment: Is there any reason to first add *all* the elements, and then remove the unnecessary ones, instead of only removing the ones from `c1` that are already contained in `c2`?

Comment: I create a new collection in order not to change the input parameters. If, for example, one of the input parameters is currently being iterated on, we do not want to modify it and run into ConcurrentModificationExceptions. You could of course add only the relevant elements into the new collection but `removeIf` keeps it very readable (imho) for the purpose of SO. Once in your codebase you can improve it for performance.

Comment: Sure, *not* changing the input collections is important as part of the contract, but I think that regardless of that, the implementation could be made more efficient. However, you already mentioned possible improvements, so this should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

**Comparing**

You can achieve this without the use of any library, just using java's [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

For instance, with the following object

```
public class A {
    private String a;
    private Double b;
    private String c;
    private int d;
    // getters and setters
}
```

You can use a comparator like

```
Comparator<AA> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AA::getA)
        .thenComparing(AA::getB)
        .thenComparingInt(AA::getD);
```

This compares the fields `a`, `b` and the int `d`, skipping `c`.

The only problem here is that this won't work with null values.

---

**Comparing nulls**

One possible solution to do a fine grained configuration, that is allow to check for specific null fields is using a `Comparator` class similar to:

```
// Comparator for properties only, only writed to be used with Comparator#comparing
public final class PropertyNullComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
                                            implements Comparator<Object> {
    private PropertyNullComparator() {  }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> PropertyNullComparator<T> of() {
        return new PropertyNullComparator<>();
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
            if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
                Comparable<Object> comparable = (Comparable<Object>) o1;
                return comparable.compareTo(o2);
            } else {
                // this will throw a ccn exception when object is not comparable
                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
                Comparable<Object> comparable = (Comparable<Object>) o2;
                return comparable.compareTo(o1) * -1; // * -1 to keep order
            }
        } else {
            return o1 == o2 ? 0 : (o1 == null ? -1 : 1); // nulls first
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can use a comparator specifying the allowed null fields.

```
Comparator<AA> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AA::getA)
        .thenComparing(AA::getB, PropertyNullComparator.of())
        .thenComparingInt(AA::getD);
```

---

If you don't want to define a custom comparator you can use something like:

```
Comparator<AA> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AA::getA)
        .thenComparing(AA::getB, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparingInt(AA::getD);
```

---

**Difference  method**

The difference (A - B) method could be implemented using two `TreeSets`.

```
static <T> TreeSet<T> difference(Collection<T> c1, 
                                 Collection<T> c2, 
                                 Comparator<T> comparator) {
    TreeSet<T> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>(comparator); treeSet1.addAll(c1);
    if (treeSet1.size() > c2.size()) {
        treeSet1.removeAll(c2);
    } else {
        TreeSet<T> treeSet2 = new TreeSet<>(comparator); treeSet2.addAll(c2);
        treeSet1.removeAll(treeSet2);
    }
    return treeSet1;
}
```

note: a `TreeSet` makes sense to be used since we are talking of uniqueness with a specific comparator. Also could perform better, the `contains` method of `TreeSet` is `O(log(n))`, compared to a common `ArrayList` that is `O(n)`.

Why only a `TreeSet` is used when `treeSet1.size() > c2.size()`, this is because when the condition is not met, the `TreeSet#removeAll`, uses the `contains` method of the second collection, this second collection could be any java collection and its `contains` method its not guaranteed to work exactly the same as the `contains` of the first `TreeSet` (with custom comparator).

---

**Edit (Given the more context of the question)**

Since collection1 is a set that could contains repeated elements acording to the custom `equals` (not the `equals` of the object) the solution already provided in the question could be used, since it does exactly that, without modifying any of the input collections and creating a new output set.

So you can create your own static function (because at least i am not aware of a library that provides a similar method), and use the `Comparator` or a `BiPredicate`.

```
static <T> Set<T> difference(Collection<T> collection1, 
                             Collection<T> collection2, 
                             Comparator<T> comparator) {
    collection1.stream()
            .filter(element1 -> !collection2.stream()
                    .anyMatch(element2 -> comparator.compare(element1, element2) == 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**Edit (To Eugene)**

*"Why would you want to implement a null safe comparator yourself"*

At least to my knowledge there isn't a comparator to compare fields when this are a simple and common null, the closest that i know of is (to raplace my sugested `PropertyNullComparator.of()` [clearer/shorter/better name can be used]):

```
Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

So you would have to write that line for every field that you want to compare. Is this doable?, of course it is, is it practical?, i think not.

Easy solution, create a helper method.

```
static class  ComparatorUtils {
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> shnp() { // super short null comparator
        return Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.<T>naturalOrder());
    }
}
```

Do this work?, yes this works, is it practical?, it looks like, is it a great solution? well that depends, many people consider the exaggerated (and/or unnecessary) use of helper methods as an anti-pattern, (a good old article by [Nick Malik](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickmalik/2005/09/06/are-helper-classes-evil/)). There are some reasons listed there, but to make things short, this is an OO language, so OO solutions are normally preferred to static helper methods.

---

*"As stated in the documentation : Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. Further, the same problem would arise in the other case, when size() > c.size() because ultimately this would still call equals in the remove method. So they both have to implement Comparator and equals consistently for this to work correctly"*

The javadoc says of [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/util/TreeSet.html) the following, but with a clear if:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals **if it is to correctly implement the Set interface**

Then says this:

> See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals

If you go to the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) javadoc says:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals

If we continue to read the javadoc again from Comparable (even in the same paragraph) says the following:

> This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare ) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

By this last quote and with a very simple code debug, or even a reading, you can see the use of an internal [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), and that all its derivated methods are based on the `comparator`, not the `equals` method;

---

*"Why is this so implemented? because there is a difference when removing many elements from a little set and the other way around, as a matter of fact same stands for addAll"*

If you go to the definition of `removeAll` you can see that its implementation is in `AbstractSet`, it is not overrided. And this implementation uses a `contains` from the argument collection when this is larger, the beavior of this `contains` is uncertain, it isn't necessary (nor probable) that the received collection (e.g. list, queue, etc) has/can define the same comparator.

**Update 1:**
This jdk bug is being discussed (and considerated to be fixed) in here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6394757

Comment: why would you want to implement a null safe comparator *yourself*?

Comment: *as we are using a custom comparator this wouldn't work for collections with another or no comparator at all*, yes this would not work. As stated in the documentation : `Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface`. Further, the same problem would arise in the other case, when `size() > c.size()`  because ultimately this would still call `equals` in the `remove` method. So they *both* have to implement `Comparator` and equals consistently for this to work correctly

Comment: why is this so implemented? because there is a difference when removing many elements from a little set and the other way around, as a matter of fact same stands for `addAll`; thus `Collectors.toSet` in java-9 has this optimization : `if (left.size() < right.size()) {
                                           right.addAll(left); return right;
                                       } else {
                                           left.addAll(right); return left;
                                       ` in the `Combiner`

Comment: @Eugene i eddited the answer, too long for a comment. The last comment i did not get it at all (i cannot see something remotely similar in my answer).

Comment: I think is irresponsible to quote incomplete texts (that lead to misinterpretation).

Comment: right about the last comment, I was thinking of something else entirely, my bad, removed it. Btw, I did not downvote

Comment: about helper methods... `Spliterators`, `Arrays`, `Objects`, etc, etc - there are various arguments of pros and cons, not going to go into them. The helper method that you put here is exactly what I had in mind - and is much more readable than whatever you had before, if you agree or not is entirely your freedom (but where I work, this would have never hit production)

Comment: I've also read your update and still don't understand your point. May be I did not make my point clear enough. `size() > c.size()` => the smaller collection is iterated and calls `remove(bigger.next())`, `remove` internally calls `equals` in case of a `TreeSet`. ELSE when `size() < c.size()` still the smaller collection is iterated calling `contains`. Now, what this `contains` is based on (`equals` or `compareTo`) is undefined, thus my point, for this to work, you would need to correctly implement `Comparable` and `equals` in both `Collection`s.

Comment: but now it seems like we are saying the same thing, which is good. the bigger problem I have here is that TreeSet does not override removeAll to take only argument of type `T` or `? super T`, but this is a really old story (`HashMap#remove` takes an `Object` instead of `T`). To not make the same mistake - this information is here (in this comment) is a side-information that complements the previous comment

Comment: Ok, i have no problem. You are probably watching the code of abstract set, because tree set overrides remove. Also the problem i described earlier do exist, (when a collection that is not a treeset is larger) the used `contains` is from this collection (which has a 'wrong' `contains`), the contains of the treeset works as expected, all based in the comparator. The Object and generic T is not a problem (at least in this case).

Comment: I would like to hear from the downvoters, what is wrong with the answer, what can be improved, etc...

Comment: btw what are the reasons of the company where your work, of why a code like this would never hit prod

Comment: man!! what has he done to get the downvotes ?? his answers are clean... something is wrong here !!

Comment: thanks @arthur, i was getting sad. I think i'm being defamed (just kidding).

Comment: @JoseDaSilva get used to the downvotes... I stopped to care a long time ago, unless they come with comments. My company would not accept that because I would not :) seriously. we have a weird policy to get code into production through a voting system, and I would have voted no, nothing personal. ;)

Comment: @JoseDaSilva funny how I stumbled on this just now to re-read all the comments. I never said I do agree with you that if a certain collection is smaller than the other, things might break in mysterious ways. But let me point out, that it's _your_ method that is responsible for this mistake. You could easily have converted both `Collection`s you get as input to a `TreeSet` and use that.

Comment: @Eugene i did converted the collections to a `TreeSet` in the `difference` method of my answer, but only when it was necessary (when the size of the collection 2 is larger or equals than the size of collection 1).
Anyway i still consider that the `removeAll` of `TreeSet` should be overrided because it does not make much sense that the own `contains` method of the `TreeSet` is used when collection 1 is smaller and the contains of the collection 2 when is not, it is error prone IMHO, and obligates you to unnecessarily create a new `TreeSet` and provide again the comparator...

Comment: @JoseDaSilva well how would you do it differently in this case? just wondering

Comment: @JoseDaSilva and my point was that you could have converted them both to TreeSets, not one only

Comment: @Eugene here is the implementation of `removeAll` (in openjdk but equals to the implementation in oraclejdk) https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSet.java#L168

Comment: @Eugene In `TreeSet` i would just use the code of the first `if` and not checking if current coll is larger than the received coll (this if is used for performace, but as i mentioned multiple times, it relies in the `contains` of the second collection, which may behave differently when a comparator is provided, and also this `contains` can be of a greater time complexity, for example if collection 2 is an array list then the contains used is O(n)).
And yeah, i could've converted both collections at first, but why would i create a new `TreeSet` when is not necessary (coll1 smaller than coll2)?

Answer (score 0):

```
static <T> Collection<T> diff(Collection<T> minuend, Collection<T> subtrahend, BiPredicate<T, T> equals) {
    Set<Wrapper<T>> w1 = minuend.stream().map(item -> new Wrapper<>(item, equals)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Wrapper<T>> w2 = subtrahend.stream().map(item -> new Wrapper<>(item, equals)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    w1.removeAll(w2);
    return w1.stream().map(w -> w.item).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static class Wrapper<T> {
    T item;
    BiPredicate<T, T> equals;

    Wrapper(T item, BiPredicate<T, T> equals) {
        this.item = item;
        this.equals = equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // all items have same hash code, check equals
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return equals.test(this.item, ((Wrapper<T>) that).item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example showing how this is supposed to be used?

Comment: Thought items should be transformed before compared. Edited to use a custom predicate.

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

code/test:

```
package com.my;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.Equator;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Diff {

    public static class FieldEquator<T> implements Equator<T> {
        private final Function<T, Object>[] functions;

        @SafeVarargs
        public FieldEquator(Function<T, Object>... functions) {
            if (Objects.isNull(functions) || functions.length < 1) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            this.functions = functions;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equate(T o1, T o2) {
            if (Objects.isNull(o1) && Objects.isNull(o2)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (Objects.isNull(o1) || Objects.isNull(o2)) {
                return false;
            }
            for (Function<T, ?> function : functions) {
                if (!Objects.equals(function.apply(o1), function.apply(o2))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hash(T o) {
            if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
                return -1;
            }
            int i = 0;
            Object[] vals = new Object[functions.length];
            for (Function<T, Object> function : functions) {
                vals[i] = function.apply(o);
                i++;
            }
            return Objects.hash(vals);
        }
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private static <T> Set<T> difference(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b, Function<T, Object>... functions) {
        if ((Objects.isNull(a) || a.isEmpty()) && Objects.nonNull(b) && !b.isEmpty()) {
            return new HashSet<>(b);
        } else if ((Objects.isNull(b) || b.isEmpty()) && Objects.nonNull(a) && !a.isEmpty()) {
            return new HashSet<>(a);
        }

        Equator<T> eq = new FieldEquator<>(functions);

        Collection<T> res = CollectionUtils.removeAll(a, b, eq);
        res.addAll(CollectionUtils.removeAll(b, a, eq));

        return new HashSet<>(res);
    }

    /**
     * Test
     */

    @Builder
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class A {
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<A> as1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<A> as2 = new HashSet<>();

        A a1 = A.builder().a("1").b("1").c("1").build();
        A a2 = A.builder().a("1").b("1").c("2").build();
        A a3 = A.builder().a("2").b("1").c("1").build();
        A a4 = A.builder().a("1").b("3").c("1").build();
        A a5 = A.builder().a("1").b("1").c("1").build();
        A a6 = A.builder().a("1").b("1").c("2").build();
        A a7 = A.builder().a("1").b("1").c("6").build();

        as1.add(a1);
        as1.add(a2);
        as1.add(a3);

        as2.add(a4);
        as2.add(a5);
        as2.add(a6);
        as2.add(a7);

        System.out.println("Set1: " + as1);
        System.out.println("Set2: " + as2);

        // Check A::getA, A::getB ignore A::getC
        Collection<A> difference = difference(as1, as2, A::getA, A::getB);

        System.out.println("Diff: " + difference);
    }
}
```

result:

```
Set1: [Diff.A(a=2, b=1, c=1), Diff.A(a=1, b=1, c=1), Diff.A(a=1, b=1, c=2)]
Set2: [Diff.A(a=1, b=1, c=6), Diff.A(a=1, b=1, c=2), Diff.A(a=1, b=3, c=1), Diff.A(a=1, b=1, c=1)]
Diff: [Diff.A(a=1, b=3, c=1), Diff.A(a=2, b=1, c=1)]
```