# How to work with Set Differences in Java using objects?

Tags: java, collections, set

I need to obtain a set difference between two sets/lists but the objects in these sets are constructed differently. I would like the set difference be calculated on only one field of these objects, how can I do this?

```
POJO o1 = new POJO();
o1.setName("Bean");
o1.setLocation("Boston");

POJO o2 = new POJO();
o2.setName("Bagel");
o2.setLocation("NYC");

POJO o3 = new POJO();
o3.setName("Bean");

List<POJO> p1 = new ArrayList<>();
p1.add(o1);
p1.add(o2);

List<POJO> p2 = new ArrayList<>();
p2.add(o3);

Collection<POJO> subList = CollectionUtils.subtract(p1, p2);
System.out.println("subList: "+subList.toString());
```

The output I see is : `subList: [POJO(name=Bean)]` i.e. `o3`. But for my use case, `o1` and `o3` are the same - how can I achieve this? I overrode the default `equals()` method as well but i don't think it is invoked.

Comment: I had to search to see where `CollectonUtils` was from.  It appears to be from `Apache`.  An overloaded version takes a predicate as the third argument for determining which values to subtract.  Please update your tags to include the appropriate third party API reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324437/is-there-a-simple-way-in-java-to-get-the-difference-between-two-collections-usin/49332217#49332217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of overloaded [subtract with predicate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate-).

1. Override `hashcode` and `equals` in `POJO` class, (and toString for clean output)

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       POJO pojo = (POJO) o;
       return Objects.equals(name, pojo.name);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return name.hashCode();
   }
   ```
2. Use Predicate with set as

   ```
   Collection<POJO> subList = CollectionUtils.subtract(p1, p2, new Predicate<POJO>() {
       @Override
       public boolean evaluate(POJO object) {
           return p1.contains(object); // might need to make p1 final
       }
   });
   ```

Result:

> subList: [ Bagel ]

**Note**: Apache common does not support anything like [Java 8 BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html)

Comment: This is incredible! I didn't know we could override the Predicate in the `subtract` method. Thanks a ton for this!

Comment: I am glad that I could help, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
POJO o1 = new POJO();
o1.setName("Bean");
o1.setLocation("Boston");

POJO o2 = new POJO();
o2.setName("Bagel");
o2.setLocation("NYC");

POJO o3 = new POJO();
o3.setName("Bean");

HashingStrategy<POJO> strategy = HashingStrategies.fromFunction(POJO::getName);

MutableSet<POJO> set1 =
        HashingStrategySets.mutable.with(strategy, o1, o2);
MutableSet<POJO> set2 =
        HashingStrategySets.mutable.with(strategy, o3);
MutableSet<POJO> difference = set1.difference(set2);

Assert.assertEquals("[POJO(name=Bagel)]", difference.toString());
```

[This answer](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) explains how `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy` works in more detail.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.